# How reverse an include pattern path in Django

Tags: django, tastypie

Hi i am wondering how i can reverse a urlpattern path that uses include pattern. Since there is no namespace i don't know how to reverse it.
Also i am new to Django so all this is a little bizarre to me.

```
v1_api = Api(api_name='v1')
urlpatterns = [path('', include(v1_api.urls))] + restless.get_urls()
```

I want to use `reverse('something')` `from django.urls import reverse`

```
  class SiteResource(ModelResource):      
    baselayer = fields.ToOneField(
    'DataLayerResource',        
    'baselayer',
     null=True)

 class Meta(ModelResource.Meta):        
      queryset = models.Site.objects.all()        
      resource_name = 'site'        
      authorization = SiteAuthorization()       
      validation = CleanedDataFormValidation(form_class=SiteForm)        
      detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', ]        
      list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']        
      excludes = []        
      abstract = False        
      filtering = {            
      'site_name': ALL,            
      'verbose_site_name': ALL,            
      'site_id': ALL,            
      'site_path': ALL,            
      'extent': ALL,        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Tastypie's source code there are a few standard methods which are implemented which you can find over [here](https://github.com/django-tastypie/django-tastypie/blob/2700cdc31bfab886149727b2f8a737309e6b27ec/tastypie/resources.py#L341-L344)

The basic pattern to reverse a URL in Tastypie is

```py
a = reverse('<method>', kwargs={'resource_name': '<name of the resource>', 'api_name': '<api_name>'})
```

In your case, let's assume you want the URL for `api_dispatch_list`. Your name of the resource is `site` and api_name is `v1`

So the URL in this case would be

```py
url = reverse('api_dispatch_list', kwargs={'resource_name': 'site', 'api_name': 'v1'})
```

and would come out to `/api/v1/site/`